# "E dolce un canto le imparava": uso di "imparare" col significato di "insegnare"

Tags: word-usage, regional

L'uso di "imparare" col significato di "insegnare" o "far apprendere" è ben noto come tratto "popolare, erroneo ma largamente diffuso" ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/imparare/)).

È usato d'altra parte anche in letteratura (il titolo della domanda è un verso di Carducci), ed è perfettamente giustificato da un punto di vista etimologico ("procurare nel(la mente)", la propria ma anche quella di un altro), tanto che in francese questo doppio uso è parte della lingua standard.

Curiosamente anche in inglese *learn* è stato abbondantemente usato col significato di *teach* almeno dal 1382 e almeno fino al 1974 (Oxford English Dictionary), a quanto pare a causa della semplificazione fonetica di due antichi verbi distinti per *imparare* e *insegnare* che sarebbero diventati omofoni nella forma *learn* (questa risposta su [english.stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/176807/170635)); sembra che anche lì sia un uso dialettale.

Mi chiedo dunque:

1. per quale motivo viene considerato "erroneo": fu qualche "erudito" a stabilirlo, ad esempio la Crusca? oppure quest'accezione si è sviluppata solo in alcune aree, e la Toscana non era tra queste, quindi è stata rifiutata anche all'italiano standard?
2. se esistano attestazioni **letterarie** di quest'uso *in età premoderna*

UPDATE: grazie alle ricerche di @DaG è stato appurato che l'uso di *imparare* per *insegnare* è perfettamente toscano, testimoniato dalla Crusca (che ne segnala il passaggio a uso arcaico), e ancora nel 1890 era difeso contro certi eruditi "troppo zelanti". La sua fortissima stigmatizzazione nell'Italia contemporanea si potrebbe allora spiegare con la caduta in disuso dell'accezione: avendo dimenticato che è esistita legittimamente, oggi la si è creduta un errore di ignoranza/meridionalismo.

Comment: Ottima domanda! Quest'accezione è sicuramente diffusa solo in alcune aree e, nel Veneto dove sono cresciuto, è largamente percepita come un uso "meridionale". Nei cinque anni che ho vissuto a Pisa non ricordo di averla mai sentita usare non in modo ironico (al contrario di altri toscanismi come "mi' babbo" o "andiamo a giro" che invece erano molto comuni).

Comment: @DenisNardin esattamente lo stesso in Lombardia (meridionale, uso solo ironico). Su [Cruscate](http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=2590) ho trovato qualche attestazione di esistenza/non esistenza per alcuni dialetti, ma nulla che spieghi il motivo del forte (e ingiustificato, mi sembra) stigma

Comment: Questione molto interessante. Per quanto riguarda proprio la Crusca, il suo vocabolario dalla 4ª edizione (1729-38) in poi [registra anche il significato “insegnare”](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?E=5316;-1381607964;&c1=350;-7;3;-21159276;212722725;&c2=129;-39;3;40;69;1;130;32;5;40;66;1;129;-39;65;-9;69;4;130;1025;5;40;75;13;130;27;3;-1445393372;29921647;&qi=&q1=imparare&q2=&q3=&q4=&qr=null&num=20&o=115;-38489505;-1185594668;&idV=1220231;1151419804;70236548;&TDE=imparare;&TDNE=).

Comment: ...e nella [quinta edizione](http://www.lessicografia.it/cruscle/pagina.jsp?ediz=5&vol=8&tipo=3&pag=167) (a cavallo fra '800 e '900) si dice addirittura «ma in tale significato oggi si userebbe più che altro in poesia» e vengono dati alcuni esempi che non ho tempo di trascrivere (soprattutto, è faticoso andare a sciogliere le abbreviazioni che danno gli estremi delle citazioni).

Comment: @DaG questo è davvero notevole... sia la Crusca sia l'autore citato (Giovanni Maria Cecchi) sia Carducci in effetti sono tutti toscani... l'esclusione dall'italiano standard mi sembra ancora più strana

Comment: @DaG notevole anche l'uso con significato "indicare", nella quinta edizione

Comment: Giusto, va approfondito. Per aggiungere un ulteriore piccolo dato, l'uso a Roma è anche classico. Il Belli, per esempio, scrive: «Per imparaje a vive e a stà a sto monno».

Comment: è possibile ipotizzare che l'uso sia diventato dapprima arcaico, poi – dimenticata la sua esistenza – sia stato stigmatizzato credendolo ingenuamente un "errore da meridionali"?

Comment: Parrebbe qualcosa del genere. Ulteriore dato: nel *Lessico dell'infima e corrotta italianità* di Fanfani e Arlía (una raccolta in forma di dizionario di pulci che gli autori – un toscano e un calabrese ma «[tra i più vigorosi sostenitori della toscanità della lingua](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/costantino-arlia_(Dizionario-Biografico)/)» – facevano all'italiano della loro epoca), di cui ho sotto mano la 3ª edizione, del 1890, si legge: [segue]

Comment: [segue] «Per [= Usato al posto di] *Insegnare*, fu ripreso [= criticato] da' troppo zelanti; ma il troppo zelo nuoce, perché gli esempii non mancano; e perché altri verbi subjettivi pigliano qualità objettiva».

Comment: @DaG un ottimo ritrovamento.. sembrerebbe di capire che questi *troppo zelanti* sostenessero che un verbo di diatesi media ("subjettivo") non possa essere usato come attivo transitivo ("objettivo")

Comment: sembrerebbe proprio che l'accusa di errore sia illegittima, quell'osservazione non è molto convincente

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14778/is-learn-the-new-teach - https://www.quora.com/Is-it-grammatically-correct-to-say-Thatll-learn-you

Comment: Aggiungerei Pietro Aretino (Lettere): «Imperoché se il canuto del tempo, che più di quindici lustri gli è suto maestro, non gli ha *imparato* tal cosa, uno indocile si puote chiamare discepolo».

Comment: splendida aggiunta, grazie

Answer (score 1):

Oltre a quanto esposto nei commenti, secondo [questo sito web](http://www.ballanti.it/articoli.htm),
sembra che anche influenze dialettali (calabresi e napoletane in questo caso) e una scarsa scolarizzazione siano responsabili dell'uso scorretto dei due verbi in questione (grassetto mio):

> Capita spesso di sentir confondere due verbi come “insegnare” ed “imparare”.

> - Alla base dell’errore c’è spesso l’ignoranza della lingua italiana, ma anche il dialetto incide molto su questo tipo di errori. Con la scolarità di massa, infatti, non c’è più molta gente che non conosce un verbo comunissimo come “imparare”, eppure si dice “te lo imparo io” anche fra la gente “imparata”.

> Ma perchè (*sic.*) proprio questi due verbi e non altri?

> - Se parliamo in termini geografici, l’errore è diffuso un po’ in tutta Italia; in termini di età, invece, l’errore è molto frequente nei bambini non scolarizzati. ***La cosa interessante è che anche nei paesi di lingua inglese i bambini in età pre-scolare confondono “learn” e “teach”, quindi si può dedurre che non è un problema di assonanza delle due parole italiane, ma di area semantica comune.***

Influenze dialettali:

> - ***Ad un esame attento di alcuni dialetti italiani, si scopre che in provincia di Catanzaro la confusione è dovuta al fatto che in dialetto si usa un verbo unico che può avere entrambi i significati***. Una cosa analoga succede in Sicilia dove il verbo è lo stesso, ma viene usato in forma diversa (transitivo/intransitivo pronominale): ‘nzignari (insegnare) e ‘nzignarisi (imparare). “Mu ‘nzignai” significa “ho imparato” (lett: Me lo sono insegnato)... come dire che imparare equivale ad insegnare a se stessi!
>   ***Anche in napoletano si usa la stessa parola per esprimere i due concetti (imparare).***
>   I periodi di dominazione francese hanno influenzato non poco quest’uso (come pure quello di utilizzare transitivamente verbi come salire, scendere, uscire ed entrare), ma i napoletani di oggi diranno “imparare” invece di “insegnare” per scelta, non certo per ignoranza. Allo stesso modo useranno come forma di cortesia il voi invece che il lei. Il lei infatti per un napoletano esprime distacco e distanza, mentre il voi rispetto: questo però è un retaggio spagnolo.

> Possiamo concludere quindi,

> - che due possono essere i motivi della confusione: l’esecrabile ignoranza della lingua italiana (quando non è dovuta a motivi di età) e l’uso dei dialetti***, che devono essere invece studiati, tramandati e mantenuti vivi accanto alla lingua nazionale come patrimonio culturale di eccezionale valore.

Comment: Devo dissentire da questa risposta. 1: non è questione di ignoranza: il punto è proprio che l'uso di imparare per insegnare sembra non avere nessun motivo di essere vietato, in quanto ampiamente giustificato da un punto di vista sia storico-etimologico sia di attestazione (in contesti anche dotti); 2: in inglese accade lo stesso fenomeno che in Italia e in Francia: già almeno dal 1382 *learn* viene usato anche per *teach* (uso *now vulgar* secondo l'OED, ma persistente almeno fino al 1966; penso che sopravviva anche in qualche dialetto)

Comment: Concordo con @mus_siluanus: non si può parlare di “uso scorretto”, come a darlo per scontato, quando invece varie fonti lo registrano come uso legittimo (senza contare che il concetto di “scorretto” è sempre non scientifico). Semmai bisogna capire per bene dove, quando e perché sia considerato più o meno accettabile.

Comment: @DaG Purtroppo cercando su internet si trova solo rimpallato dall'uno all'altro il fraintendimento che sia un errore, ma nessuno che spieghi per quale motivo sarebbe un errore.

Comment: Concordo con le critiche fatte dall'OP e @DaG nei suoi commenti. Mi pare anche che l'Accademia della Crusca (si veda un'altra risposta a questa domanda per i dettagli) dissenta con il contenuto di questo post: non si tratta del fatto che sia un "uso scorretto" del verbo "imparare", ma di tenere conto di quale registro o varietà della lingua si stia usando. Secondo me, affermare come si fa qui che questo uso di "imparare" è scorretto sarebbe simile a dire che usare il vocabolo ["alquanto" di cui si chiedeva in questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12852/) è un errore.

Comment: Inoltre, non si risponde alla domanda che chiede "se esistano attestazioni letterarie di quest'uso in età premoderna".

Answer (score 1):

Secondo questo [articolo di Riccardo Cimaglia per l'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/emimparareem-e-eminsegnareem-non-sono-la-stessa-cosa/1710), si tratta di un uso regionale centro-meridionale del verbo "imparare":

> Sempre il Sabatini-Coletti registra l’uso regionale centro-meridionale (che trova riscontro in moltissimi dialetti, tra cui il napoletano e il romanesco, che usa *insegnà(re)* nel senso di ‘indicare’) del verbo *imparare* con il valore di “insegnare qlco. a qlcu., specialmente con il primo argomento espresso da frase (introdotto da a): *ha imparato a scrivere al figlio*”.

L'articolo afferma che esistono attestazioni letterarie di questo uso a partire del Cinquecento e ne dà alcuni esempi, tra i quali i versi di Carducci citati nella domanda:

> Questa accezione del verbo *imparare* è attestata anche in testi letterari, a partire dal secolo XVI:
>
> > Se il canuto del tempo, che più di quindici lustri gli è suto maestro, non gli ha imparato tal cosa, uno indocile si può chiamare discepolo (Pietro Aretino, *Lettere*); 
> > Dubito che abbia potuto trovarsi nella lingua tedesca tutto intero quel poetico che le regole non insegnano e gli studi non imparano (Pietro Giordani, *Volgarizzamento di un discorso della baronessa di Staël: Sulla maniera e la utilità delle traduzioni*, 1816); 
> > Essa la diva / con le dita d’ambrosia, essa da gli occhi / tergea de la mortal giovine il pianto; / e dolce un canto le imparava (Giosue Carducci, *Juvenilia*, LXVII, *Maggio e Novembre*, vv. 37-40);
> > Quello là vuol far l’offeso eh? Adesso glielo imparo io: non gli telefono per almeno un mese (Dino Buzzati, *Un amore*, 1963).

Il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI07/00000409.jpg) riporta altri esempi letterari (il primo è lo stesso testo Cinquecentesco dell'Aretino già citato):

> *Aretino*, IV-5-210: Se il canuto del tempo, che più di quindici lustri gli è suto maestro, non gli ha imparato tal cosa, uno indocile si puote chiamare discepolo. *Belo*, 16: Volmi imparare il dirupisti e farmi toccar co' le
> mani la resurrezione della carne. *G. M. Cecchi*, 7-5-5: Deh sì, Pallottola, / imparami un miccin, come e' si fanno. / S'io sapessi far l'arte, io la farei / per me. *G. Florio*, 2-14-19: Fuge finalmente la virtù di temperanza l'ozio, non potend'ella patire ch'ei renda l'anima e 'l corpo languidi, imparandogli il mal fare. *L. Pascoli*,
> 1-171: Era... desideroso d'imparare altrui in poca d'ora ciocché egli imparato avea nel lungo corso dell'età sua. *Esercizi militari*, 186: È bene di far più volte questa operazione sino a che l'abbino ben capita i soldati a cavallo, per poi imparargli i diversi moti dello squadrone. *Giordani*, 1-1-262: Dubito che abbia potuto travasarsi
> nella lingua tedesca tutto intero quel poetico che le regole non insegnano e gli studi non imparano. *Pisacane*, 1-30: L'insopportabile tirannide impara al popolo ed al Senato
> i mali gravissimi che il concedere ad un uomo tanto potere cagionava. *Carducci*, III-2-150: Essa la diva, / con le dita d'ambrosia, essa da gli occhi / tergea de la
> mortal giovine il pianto; / e dolce un canto le imparava. *Saba*, 239: Fare in te una Madonna d'una scaltra monella? / Questo il vino t'impara? *Buzzati*, 6-268: Quello
> là vuol far l'offeso eh? Adesso glielo imparo io: non gli telefono per almeno un mese.

L'articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca sopra citato raccomanda evitare questo uso in un registro standard poiché nell'italiano contemporaneo è considerato appartenente a varietà regionali e popolari della lingua (questa è la ragione per cui a volte si parla di uso "erroneo"):

> Nonostante queste attestazioni, raccomandiamo ai nostri lettori di evitare quest’uso, oggi considerato improprio, ristretto alle varietà regionali e popolari, e di attenersi alla norma.

Quindi, per quanto riporta l'articolo citato, si tratta di un'accezione del termine che, di forma in certo modo simile a quello che è successo al vocabolo ["almanco" di cui si parlava qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12852/), è sopravvissuta soltanto in alcune varietà regionali (e anche in registri popolari).