# Almanco: è un termine antico o regionale?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Leggendo un racconto di Leopardi, "Dialogo di Federico Ruysch e delle sue mummie", mi sono imbattuto nel termine *almanco* che non conoscevo. Dal contesto ho supposto il suo significato, ma poi mi è venuto un dubbio, e ho cercato su alcuni dizionari on line. Sono rimasto un po' sorpreso: per il Treccani tale parola non esiste, altri (per esempio il Gabrielli) la citano marcandola con "antico o regionale". Che significa "antico **o** regionale"? Capirei se la parola fosse marcata con entrambe le qualifiche congiunte, o con una sola.

Quindi: che termine è? Leopardi usava parole regionali?

Se può essere utile, ho trovato una copia online di tale testo: https://www.pearson.it/letteraturapuntoit/contents/files/leop_mummie.pdf

Comment: "Antico o regionale" in un dizionario significa che, in generale, il termine è caduto in disuso, ma sopravvive in qualche variante regionale.

Comment: @Hachi Direi, forse meglio: “antiquato per l'italiano letterario, ma in uso in varianti regionali”.

Comment: Sono un po' confuso da che cosa si stia chiedendo veramente. «Che significa "antico o regionale"? Capirei se la parola fosse marcata con entrambe le qualifiche congiunte»: entrambe le qualifiche congiunte, cioè con “e”, significherebbero, poniamo, che si usava solo in Veneto nel XVIII secolo. Disgiunte, cioè con “o”, vogliono dire invece che in altri tempi era parte dell'italiano ovunque lo si parlasse, mentre ora persiste solo in alcune zone.

Comment: Visto che non è stato menzionato, aggiungerei che “almanco” è un composto di [“manco”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/manco1) che a sua volta, in altri tempi e tutt'ora in certe parti d'Italia (non ovunque usato nello stesso modo), ha/aveva il valore di “meno”.

Comment: Infatti questo termine appare sul Treccani, nella voce citata da @DaG, ma scritto nella forma staccata *al manco*, dove "manco" secondo questo dizionario significa "meno". Per questa e altre locuzioni con la parola "manco", il Treccani spiega: "Sono ancora vive nell’uso pop. e region. le locuz. [...]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondo il De Mauro ***[almanco](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/almanco)*** significa:

(avv.
av. 1320; dalla locuzione  *al manco.* )

> almeno; per lo meno

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=almanco&year_start=1770&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calmanco%3B%2Cc0) mostra  che l’espressione   “almanco” (almeno) era in uso in particolare nel XIX secolo. Ad esempio:

Da [La Vita di Benvenuto Cellini, scritta da lui medesimo.](https://books.google.it/books?id=U3nccAJj2yMC&pg=PA264&dq=%22almanco%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ_t_gprvpAhXmoosKHcfUAGoQ6AEIWjAH#v=onepage&q=%22almanco%22&f=false) (1852)

> ...la tua gloriosa resurressione, che tu mi facci degno che io vegga il sole, se non è altrimenti, ***almanco in sogno;*** ma se tu mi facessi degno che io lo vedessi con questi mia occhi mortali, i0 ti prometto di venirti a visitare al tuo santo Sepulcro.

Da [Gazzetta de' tribunali](https://books.google.it/books?id=yo36jP2LUA8C&pg=PA420&dq=%22almanco%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3x4Onp7vpAhUGqYsKHfc4DIY4ChDoATACegQIARAR#v=onepage&q=%22almanco%22&f=false). (1853)

> quest'ultimo che un solo interesse, quello cioè di ricevere il prezzo della sua proprietà, ***od almanco di vedersene in legale modo guarentito il pagamento.***

“Almanco sopravvive come termine dialettale in [Veneto](http://www.linguaveneta.net/linguaveneta/wp-content/plugins/pdfjs-viewer-shortcode/pdfjs/web/viewer.php?file=/linguaveneta/wp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F09%2FDizionario-italiano-veneto.pdf&download=false&print=false&openfile=false) e in [Friuli](https://it.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Dizionario_-_Vocabolario_del_dialetto_triestino/A) .

Alla luce di quanto sopra direi che “almanco” è un termine desueto nella lingua italiana ma di uso corrente a livello regionale.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!